# Android: GridLayout rows are all bunched together

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-gridlayout

Im making using a Grid Layout on an app. The Columns work fine but the rows are giving me a problem.

I want 4 rows spread evenly on the image I am using. But for some reason the rows are all bunched up with only the last row ahead of the others. **Its my first time using a GridLayout and i cant see what im doing wrong.**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:src="@drawable/pitch"/>

<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:rowCount="4"
    android:numColumns="5"
    android:id="@+id/formation"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Gk"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/gk"
        android:layout_columnSpan="3" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="DL"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/dl" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="DC"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/dcl" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="DC"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/dcr" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="DR"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="4"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/dr" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ML"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/ml" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="MC"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/mcl" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="MC"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/mcr" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="MR"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="4"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/mr" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="FC"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/fcl" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="FC"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/fcr" />

</GridLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: use linearlayout instead of gridlayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggest you to use `linearlayout` instead of `gridlayout`, to set image in background you need to use `FrameLayout` as in below code,

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/next"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/formation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="4">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/formation1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/gk"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Gk" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/formation2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/dl"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="DL" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/dcl"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="DC" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/dcr"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="DC" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/dr"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="DR" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/formation3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/ml"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="ML" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/mcl"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="MC" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/mcr"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="MC" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/mr"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="MR" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/formation4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/fcl"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="FC" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/fcr"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="FC" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

hope this is usefull.

Comment: tell me if facing any issue @discodowney

Comment: Cheers for the answer but i go tit working using layout_columnWeight and layout_rowWeight. But ill keep this in mind for the future in case the grid causes me some other problems. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Consider instead using a vertical LinearLayout containing horizontal LinearLayouts (or more GridLayouts) for each row. Then each row view can have a layout_weight set to the same value so they are all allocated the same amount of space.  In that case also set their layout_height to 0.

Comment: But I want the buttons spread out over the whole image. If I remove the match parent and make it wrap content all the buttons are bunched together in the top half of the image. Can you tell me how I get the rows to spread evenly out over the whole image?

Comment: Got it. I had to supply android:layout_columnWeight="1" and         android:layout_rowWeight="1" to each button

Answer (score 0):

You can add:

```
android:layout_columnWeight="1"
android:layout_rowWeight="1"
```

in each Button. Like this:

```
<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:rowCount="4"
    android:numColumns="5"
    android:id="@+id/formation"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Gk"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/gk"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnSpan="3" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="DL"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/dl" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="DC"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/dcl" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="DC"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:layout_gravity="centerl"
        android:id="@+id/dcr" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="DR"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_column="4"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/dr" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ML"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/ml" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="MC"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/mcl" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="MC"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/mcr" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="MR"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_column="4"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/mr" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="FC"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/fcl" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="FC"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/fcr" />

</GridLayout>
```